# run a private EOS fork on Raspberry Pi

Tags: blockchains

for development purposes, is it possible to run a private version of EOS on a Raspberry Pi?

what are the required steps to fork, build, then run it on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes! But you have to meet the specification required for EOS on R-Pi.

Comment: I tried to deploy EOS on RPi 3 Model B. By using the docker compose method: it crashed when building docker containers on 'exec user process caused "exec format error"' -> This is highly likely because the docker containers are designed for x64 architecture and not for RPi's ARM. And by using the auto build method: it was frozen after couple minutes of running.

Comment: there are alternatives that use x64 architecture. They cost a little bit more, but for sure it's fun to experiment with it. Make sure it's got minimum 8GB of ram